# Настройка доступа в интернет в Linux через ПК с Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, доступ

День добрый

Не получается настроить доступ в интеренет в Linux (на промышленном контроллере). Контроллер подключен по локальной сети к ноутбуку с Windows10. В интернет в ноутбуке выхожу через Wi-Fi соединение. В беспроводном соединении на ноуте в настройках беспроводной карты галочку в общем доступе поставил. Сетевой карте ноута (которая подключена к контроллеру) сразу присвоился IP-адрес 192.168.137.1 (маска 255.255.255.0). Я соответственно присвоил сетевой карте контроллера 192.168.137.63.

Антивирус и брандмауэр на ноутбуке отключил. Ping между контроллером и ноутбуком проходит. А вот ping с контроллера например по адресу 8.8.8.8 нет.

Через программу WinSCP с ноута я могу зайти в контроллер.

Как настроить доступ в Интернет в контроллере через ноутбук?

Comment: default gateway в контроллере скорее всего неправильный, попробуте через dhcp контроллер подключить

Answer (score 0):

## 1.1 Исходные данные

ПЛК по LAN подключен к ПК (ОС Windows 10). На ПК доступ в Интернет через беспроводную сетевую карту (далее - СК1).
Сетевая карта ПК подключенная к LAN - СК2. Сетевая карта ПЛК - СК3.

Указанные ниже IP-адреса условные.

## 1.2 Последовательность действий

Для доступа в сеть Интернет у ПЛК через другой компьютер ПК необходимо проделать следующее:
- на ПК между СК1 и СК2 сделать мост;
- на ПЛК для СК3 запросить IP-адрес по DHCP

```
$ dhclient eth0
```

- установить IP-адрес, маску сети и broadcast-адрес

```
$ ip addr add 192.168.0.120/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255 dev eth0
```

- указать IP-адрес шлюза (см. сведения созданного сетевого моста на ПК)

```
$ ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

- проверить из командной строки ПЛК доступность Интернета

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```